# Doctrine Problem: Couldn't get last insert identifier

Tags: orm, doctrine

When i try to save data to my model Doctrine throws this exception:

```
Message: Couldn't get last insert identifier.
```

My table setup code is:

```
$this->hasColumn('id', 'integer', 4, array(
         'type' => 'integer',
         'length' => 4,
         'fixed' => false,
         'unsigned' => false,
         'primary' => true,
         'autoincrement' => true,
         ));
```

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Check to make sure that the column in your database is set up as auto_increment. It looks like the Doctrine class is handling it as an auto_increment but it's not set up as such in the DB.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this more times than one. You just made a gnarly bug have a 10 minute fix.

Answer (score 2):

For me, the problem was the `default` paramater.

```
        $this->hasColumn('inscription_id', 'integer', 4, array(
         'type' => 'integer',
         'length' => 4,
         'fixed' => false,
         'unsigned' => false,
         'primary' => true,
 //        'default' => '0', !!! get "couldn't get last inserted identifier doctrine"
         'notnull' => true,
         'autoincrement' => true,
         ));
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
$this->hasColumn('cd_fabricante', 'integer', 4, array(
          'type' => 'integer',
          'length' => 4,
          'unsigned' => true,
          'primary' => true,
          'auto_increment' => true,
) );
```

Had the same parameters as you previously, same error too.

EDIT: I recently found about adding "auto_increment" to the PK column definition and now I it behaves the same as any given ID field handled by Doctrine with whatever name I choose